# Using lex and Yacc to parse php

Tags: php, parsing, yacc, lex, lexical-analysis

i want to create a php parser.i was thinking of using lex/yacc for the task.

is that a good idea ? or there are better ways ?

where can i find an already made lex/yacc for php language. or at least the grammer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Zend/zend_language_parser.y .

Comment: You'd need the lex file, too, and you still haven't got a tree to work on.

Answer (score 0):

See our [PHP Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/PHPFrontEnd.html).  This is not built using traditional LEX and YACC, but has the advantage of a huge effort to define a robust parser, and hard knock testing over several years at this point.  Using a fully elaborated grammar, it parses full PHP5 (that's hard, the language is poorly defined), including picking up all the details about interpolated string values, automatically builds ASTs, and can prettyprint ASTs back to completely valid PHP source text preserving layout, including comments.

Invariably there is life beyond parsing. and one needs tools to support the analysis or modification of the code to achieve the actual purpose.  The engine underlying the PHP Front End, the [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html), provides the LEX- and YACC-like machinery we use and additionally provides the ability to procedurally navigate/inspect/modify the ASTs, provides source-to-source rewrite rules for pattern-matching and/or transformation of code, supports building of symbol tables, and provides a control and data flow analysis framework.  This machinery makes it much easier to focus on getting the job done, rather than trying to implement such machinery ad hoc as you encounter the need.  (DMS actually handles a wide variety of languages using front ends as means of integration).

Comment: Is this a known bug that name definitions in lex doesn't work(I have to copy the regex to the rules section to make it work, my lex version is `2.5.4`)? I saw two posts here on the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971581/have-problem-with-lex and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602156/definitions-in-lex-not-working-but-when-regex-copied-into-rules-it-works

Comment: @Je Rog: Sorry, are you asking me to tell you why lex 2.5.4 isn't behaving the way you expect? 1) SO etiquette says if you have a question to ask, then do so as a question or if you have found a question that is ideal, vote it up and/or elaborate in a comment, and 2) actually I don't know the answer to your question.  Despite having built a a working PHP parser, we don't use traditional YACC or LEX; rather we use our own internal tools that are LEX-like and YACC-like. They have named definitions like LEX, which work like you want LEX's to work, but that's irrelevant to your specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the rphp_grammar.y in rphp_grammar's github  [rphp_grammar](https://github.com/weyrick/roadsend-php-raven/blob/master/compiler/analysis/grammar_src/rphp_grammar.y)