# Have problem with lex

Tags: lex

My lex as follows:

```
LNUM    [0-9]+
DNUM([0-9]*"."[0-9]+)|([0-9]+"."[0-9]*)                                                                                    
%%
{LNUM} {
printf("\t");ECHO;printf("\r\n");
}

{DNUM} {
printf("\t");ECHO;printf("\r\n");
}
```

But it turns out that it can only match numbers like `4.12` `.2`,not `42`,`45.`  etc.(those indented are matched)

Output:

```
1.
1.
.1
    .1

12
12
```

My target is to match both integers and float numbers.

Can anyone here tell me what's wrong above?

Comment: Is that your complete LEX file? What are you doing to handle whitespace?  Can you show an exact log of running lex, and then running yylex, along with an exact copy of the input you provided?

Comment: @Ira Baxter ,yes it's the **complete** LEX file.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer to your question... but for what it's worth, I tried replacing the `*` you had in the original lex file (the second pattern for `DNUM`) with a `+` (because that ensures that you at least have one digit to the right of the decimal point in order for the number to be counted as a decimal...) and it seems to work for me, at least.  Hope this helps someone in the future.

---

**lex file:**

```
%{
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
%}

LNUM    [0-9]+
DNUM    ([0-9]*"."[0-9]+)|([0-9]+"."[0-9]+) 

%option noyywrap

%%
{LNUM}*  { cout << "lnum: " << yytext << endl; }
{DNUM}*  { cout << "dnum: " << yytext << endl; }
%%

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

---

**example input (on command line):**

```
$ echo "4.12 .2 42 45. " | ./lexer
dnum: 4.12
dnum: .2
lnum: 42
lnum: 45.
```